# svg tag hides anything after it inside the html body

Tags: html, svg

In this simple example, only the section A is displayed (with Chromium Version 28.0.1500.71), not section B which is just after the svg tag.

Is it normal behaviour and why, am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in chrome ?

```
<html>
<body>

<section>
    <H1>THis is section A</H1>
</section>

<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5">
  </rect>

  <foreignObject x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150">
        <H2>This is H2 text embedded in svg</H2>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</div>

<section>
    <H1>This is section B and should be displayed</H1>
</section>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS? cuz it works kwel for me http://jsfiddle.net/SGfRA/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't display the line "This is section B and should be displayed"

Comment: I can see that on firefox as well as chrome

Comment: so maybe it's a bug in chromium, i'm gonna check firefox

Comment: you're right, it prints ok with firefox

Comment: Working on my end : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqLju/). Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari. The SVG does not look perfect in Firefox but section B is visible.

Comment: there's probably a gap between chrome and chromium

Comment: Yes, it's a gap, but chrome does render

Comment: You're missing height and width attributes on the `<svg>` element. Adding these will improve things on Firefox. This is a webkit bug that it displays as it does without these attributes.

Comment: What Robert said. See http://jsfiddle.net/SGfRA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox displays the data accordingly.
So it's a bug in Chromium Version 28.0.1500.71.

**Edit**: As commenters have said, putting width and/or height is sufficient for a correct rendering. Thus, that being said, it is then only a minor bug.